# What should I use to replace queryParamsHandling in Angular 12?

Tags: angular, query-string

I had angular 10 appplication.In one of my pages i had the following code

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(SUPPORTED_URI.DEPLOYMENT_DASHBOARD, {queryParamsHandling: 'merge'});
```

after i updated my code to angular version 11, angular automatically removed queryParamsHandling from my code and now i have the following

```
                this.router.navigateByUrl(SUPPORTED_URI.DEPLOYMENT_DASHBOARD, /* Removed unsupported properties by Angular migration: queryParamsHandling. */ {});
```

what should I use now ? Why in angular there is no info about that this thing is depricated

https://angular.io/api/router/QueryParamsHandling

What should I use instead so my code will be not broken ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular split navigation options since v11, so you need to use `createUrlTree` method to build navigation tree and then navigate. Here is the comment [explaining this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/39345#issuecomment-713094611).

So you need to update the code to something like this:

```js
const urlTree = this.router.createUrlTree(SUPPORTED_URI.DEPLOYMENT_DASHBOARD, {queryParamsHandling: 'merge'});

this.router.navigateByUrl(urlTree);
```